# How to extract a specific character inside a parentheses using sed command?

Tags: sed

I want to extract an atomic symbols inside a parentheses using sed.

The data I have is in the form `C(X12)`, and I only want the X symbol

EX: that a test command :

```
echo "C(Br12)" | sed 's/[0-9][0-9])$//g'
```

gives me `C(Br`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -n 's/.*(\(.*\)[0-9]\{2\})$/\1/p'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/8EiqkY):

```sh
sed -n 's/.*(\(.*\)[0-9]\{2\})$/\1/p' <<< "c(Br12)"
# => Br
```

*Details*

- `-n` - suppresses the default line output
- `.*(\(.*\)[0-9]\{2\})$` - a regex that matches

  - `.*`  - any text
  - `(` - a `(` char
  - `\(.*\)` - Capturing group 1: any text up to the last....
  - `[0-9]\{2\}` - two digits
  - `)$` - a `)` at the end of string
- `\1` - replaces with Group 1 value
- `p` - prints the result of the substitution.

Comment: Dear Wiktor Stribiżew, Thank you very much for your reply, it work perfectly for one item, but when i try it for a txt file containing for example 20  C(X--) give me nothing.

Comment: @anasforum Then what is the rule? I used this pattern because you tried to match two digits and `)`. So , I understood you wanted to get the substring after `(` and up to 2 digits + `)`. Try `sed -n 's/.*(\([^0-9()]*\)[^()]*)$/\1/p`, see [this online demo](https://ideone.com/b3PUXX).

Comment: @anasforum Does https://ideone.com/b3PUXX work better? `sed -n 's/.*(\([^0-9()]*\)[^()]*)$/\1/p`? If not, please add more test cases to the question.

Comment: Dear All, Thank you very much for your precious help, finally it works, and that's my command sed 's/C(\([a-zA-Z]*\).*/\1/' , i apply it to text file containing a 20 items and work perfectly.  special thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
echo "C(Br12)" | sed 's/C(\(.\).*/\1/'
```

- `C(` - match exactly literally `C(`
- `.` match anything
- `\(.\)` - match anythig - one character- and "remember" it in a backreference `\1`
- `.*` ignore everything behind it
- `\1` - replace it by the stuff that was remembered. The first character.

Research `sed`, regex and backreferences for more information.

Comment: Dear KamilCuk, Thank you very much for your reply, but your command give only the B, not Br.

Comment: Then match `\(..\)`. Learn regex. I recommend regex crosswords, they are great for learning. Or match `\([^0-9]*\)`, I don't know what pattern is intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following command

```
echo "C(BR12)" | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1 | sed 's/[0-9]*//g'
```

The cut tool will split and get you the string in middle of the paranthesis.Then pass the string to a sed for replacing the numbers inside the string.

Not a fully sed solution but this will get you the output.